# Makefile - Select names from list using mask

Tags: makefile

I have Makefile in which I get a list of files from a certain directory. I need to choose only those, in the names of which there are numbers (like `123.txt`). What is the best way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: please read  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [glob](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcards) or [`wildcard`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcard-Function), for example:

```
all.txt: text/*.txt
    cat $^ >> $@
```

Usage:

```
$ cd -- "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ mkdir text
$ echo foo > text/1.txt
$ echo bar > text/2.txt
$ make
cat text/1.txt text/2.txt >> all.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NUMBER_FILENAMES := $(shell echo " $(LIST) " | sed 's/ [^ 0-9]* / /g')
```